# Trying to make a button array but app crashes on runtime with a null pointer exception

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a note app and I want to make a activity where are buttons in. In this buttons are the names of the notes I made.

I made a button array and a for loop to make them in the `onCreate` method, but when I start the app and I click on the activity the app shut down and I get a null pointer exception.

```
package savovuksan.at.noteit; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;`

public class NotizOeffnungsMenue extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public Button[] NoteListBtn = new Button[fileList().length];
    public String[] NoteList = fileList();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notiz_oeffnungs_menue);

        for (int i = 0;i<fileList().length;i++)
        {
            NoteListBtn[i] = new Button(this);
            NoteListBtn[i].setText(NoteList[i]);
            NoteListBtn[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
09-01 11:05:08.385  17697-17697/savovuksan.at.noteit   
E/AndroidRuntime﹕FATALEXCEPTION:    main
Process: savovuksan.at.noteit, PID: 17697
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate    
activityComponentInfo{savovuksan.at.noteit/savovuksan.at.noteit.NotizOeffnungsMenue}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2129)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ContextWrapper.fileList(ContextWrapper.java:200)
at savovuksan.at.noteit.NotizOeffnungsMenue.<init>(NotizOeffnungsMenue.java:17)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the logcat trace.

Comment: In addition to the stacktrace from logcat, what is `filelist()` and why are you calling it so early in activity init / so many times?

Comment: filelist() is the list of files in the folder i saved the notes

Comment: Can you post where filelist come from? Why are you using to initialize the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the `NoteListBtn`,`NoteList`in the `onCreate()` method.

```
package savovuksan.at.noteit; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;`

public class NotizOeffnungsMenue extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


public Button[] NoteListBtn; //just declare as members
public String[] NoteList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notiz_oeffnungs_menue);

    //initialiaze
    NoteListBtn = new Button[fileList().length]; 
    NoteList = fileList();

    for (int i = 0;i<fileList().length;i++)
    {
        NoteListBtn[i] = new Button(this);
        NoteListBtn[i].setText(NoteList[i]);
        NoteListBtn[i].setOnClickListener(this);
    }





}

}
```